# QEMU and the Raspberry Pi

Tags: linux, virtualization, qemu

*[I re-titled this for posterity, since it does turn out to be* somewhat *raspberry-pi centric]*

I'd like to try QEMU as an alternative to cross-compiling.  I'm using v. 1.0.1 on fedora 17 [later: same results with 1.6 built from source], the guest image is for arm11.  I'm invoking:

```
qemu-system-arm -cpu arm1176 -m 256 -kernel [kernel] -append "root=/dev/sda" -hda [fs.img] -M versatilepb -D log.txt
```

This produces no output and pops up a blank window.  I can `ctrl-alt-2` to get the "qemu monitor" prompt, but I have no idea how to use this to tell me something about the state.

I am *absolutely positive* the kernel and the fs image are valid, as they were taken together from the actual system.  I have also tried publicly available images and kernels using instructions available on-line for the device -- this is where I got the basics of the invocation line.  I'm familiar with the creation and use of raw file system images generally.

The emulated system is from a raspberry pi, and there's [a long thread of people](http://www.raspberrypi.org/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?f=63&t=3149) mostly describing success with qemu (although as mentioned I cannot duplicate their results).  However, this is NOT a linux or rpi related question, it's a question (or three) about qemu:

1. Can QEMU comment at all about the state of the emulator?  Is there any way to get it to report something -- anything -- success -- failure -- events -- anything?  Note that it does not even create "log.txt", specified with the `-D` option, regardless of whether I 'quit' via the monitor prompt or just kill the process.
2. Does the fact that it completely maxes out one processor indicate anything?  I presume it should not be doing that.
3. Can the monitor shell be used to debug this kind of problem?

I notice that if I use `qemu-system-x86_64 -kernel [hostkernel]` the emulator window comes up and shows the output of a kernel booting, so the blank window with `-arm` implies this is a non-starter.  I'd just like to try and find out *why*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, QEMU [does not support](https://bugs.launchpad.net/qemu/+bug/1231093) the arm11v6 kernel used on the pi -- you need to create a [slightly different version](http://www.cnx-software.com/2011/10/18/raspberry-pi-emulator-in-ubuntu-with-qemu/) which apparently will still run in QEMU together with the raspbian binaries.